# What does this statement about fiducials mean?

Tags: pcb, dfm

Found this slide and I didn't understand the last statement.

> All fiducials should have same image one layer down

Are fiducials not top/bottom layer registration targets during assembly ?
Are/Can fiducials used during manufacturing to align layers prior to lamenting them ?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fiducials are registered using vision technology. Having the same image on the next layer into the board makes it clearer to a wider range of cameras.

Comment: So in other words they want superimposed fiducials on the two outmost layers of each side of the PCB?

Comment: What you want is very clear fiducials. Superimposing them exactly facilitates this.